# Users monthly reputation tab is displaying only one result

Tags: bug

When we click on [monthly users reputation page](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month) and select month tab, the names of the users and the reputation earned are not shown as intended. It returns only one result.

link : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=month

[image: monthly user reputation]

Only a user name is being displayed. It works as usual for week, quarterly and yearly tabs.

I hope this gets fixed soon.

Comment: Working fine for me.

Comment: Working for me.

Comment: @TheDestroyer It is [meta-tag:status-completed]

Comment: @Pandya It is  [meta-tag:satus-completed] or [meta-tag:status-norepro]. A dev should know what happened during that brief period of time.

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/43001906#43001906. Some dev will know what happened in the brief period of time. The screenshot shows that it shown only one user. Tags should be edited now.